# Recording darkens preview and ratios

Tags: android, android-camera

This is coded in NativeScript, so I'll try my best to adapt the scenario to Java. I have created an in-app video view with support to record the video.

This is done as follows:

First I create a `SurfaceView` that will hold the preview of the camera:

```
this.mSurfaceView = new android.view.SurfaceView(this._context);
this.mHolder = this.mSurfaceView.getHolder(); 
this.mHolder.setType(android.view.SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
```

Then I create an instance of the `Camera`, and sets the video surface:

```
var mCamera = android.hardware.Camera;
var camera = mCamera.open(1);   
this.camera = camera;
this.camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
var parameters = camera.getParameters();
parameters.setRecordingHint(true);
if( parameters.isVideoStabilizationSupported() ){
    parameters.setVideoStabilization(true);
}
camera.setParameters(parameters);
this.camera.setPreviewDisplay(_this.mHolder);
this.camera.startPreview();
this.camera.startFaceDetection();
```

Now, all is good. I have the camera preview in the view that I want it to be. The color is good and I *think* the image aspect ratio is good too.

However, when I initiate the recording, as I do with the following code:

```
this.mediarecorder = new android.media.MediaRecorder();        
// Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
this.camera.unlock();
this.mediarecorder.setCamera(this.camera);

// Step 2: Set sources
this.mediarecorder.setAudioSource(android.media.MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
this.mediarecorder.setVideoSource(android.media.MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
//this.mediarecorder.setOutputFormat(android.media.MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);

// Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)
this.mediarecorder.setProfile(android.media.CamcorderProfile.get(android.media.CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
// platform.screen.mainScreen.widthDIPs
// platform.screen.mainScreen.heightDIPs

// Step 4: Set output file
var fileName = "videoCapture_" + new Date() + ".mp4";
var path = android.os.Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath() + "/Camera/" + fileName;
this.file = new java.io.File(path);
this.mediarecorder.setOutputFile(this.file.toString());

this.mediarecorder.setOrientationHint(270);

try {
    this.mediarecorder.prepare();
    this.mediarecorder.start();
} catch( ex ) {
    console.log(ex);
}
```

Then, the image suddenly becomes darker, and my face (its what's in focus when I'm trying it out) gets wider. So the aspect ratio changes, and so does the lighting somehow.

I have tried setting setPictureSize on the camera parameters, and setVideoSize on the MediaRecorder with no luck. And for the lighting change, I have simply no clue as to whats going on. Now I've been googling myself half way to heaven, and still found nothing, so I hope someone here has got any tip on what to pursue next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Video recording generally tries to run at a steady frame rate, such as 30fps.  Camera preview often slows itself down to 10-15fps to maintain brightness, so if you're in a darker location, video recording will be darker (since it can't expose for longer than 1/30s instead of 1/10s that camera preview can).

Did you call setVideoSize before or after calling setProfile? The setProfile call changes many parameters, including preview size; most video recording sizes are 16:9, and the default camera preview resolution is likely a 4:3 size.  So when you start the recording, the aspect ratio switches.

Most video recording apps use 16:9 preview sizes even before starting recording so that they're consistent. You can also record 4:3 video, but that's generally not what people want to see.